# How to calculate the range of this function without the use of graphs?

Tags: functions

I would like to know how you can find the range of this function $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ through for example algebra

I know it is possible to calculate the asymptotes and stationary points and then draw the graph, but how can you calculate it otherwise?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the range of the function put x + 1/x =y
This will reduce to x^2 +1 -yx=0
Now since  x is real therefore  the discriminant of the above equation should be Non Negative which gives y^2 - 4 >=0 which gives  y>=2 and y<=-2.
Hence the range which is y is 
y>=2 and y<=-2

Comment: It's called "discriminant", not "determinant". Apart from that a nice answer.

Comment: @Arthur Ohh I misspelled it. Probably the auto correct feature !!! Thanks

Comment: So in other words for similar functions I must find Δ>=0 to find the range?

Comment: @RaymondSWalters It varies from example to example . Sometimes discriminant will do . Sometimes you will have to check with the domain . Like if x is always > 0 then what values can y take. Sometimes taking out maxima and minima can also be helpful. It depends on the problem. Variety of ways can work depending on the problem considered.

Comment: I see thank you for your trouble

Comment: So if you got the answer could you  mark it correct

Comment: You need the discriminant to be non-negative, i.e. $\Delta \ge 0$. Your inequalities are a little off too: if $y^2-4 > 0$ then $y<-2$ or $y>2$ (not $y \le -2$ or $y \ge 2$.)

Comment: Yes Non negative would be a better term . I have corrected it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The function is odd, so we only have to worry about $x>0.$ Since $f(x) > x,$ it is clear that $f$ takes on arbitrarily large values. What we need is the minimum value of $f$ on $(0,\infty).$ Do you know basic calculus? If so, you find the minimum value on $(0,\infty)$ is $2$ (this occurs at $x=1$). By the intermediate value theorem, $f((0,\infty)) = [2,\infty).$ Using the oddness of $f,$ we get the full range of $f$ to be $ (-\infty,-2]\cup [2,\infty).$

Comment: This appears to be similar to drawing the graph without actually drawing the graph (if you understand) because critical points such as a local minimum or maximum needs to be calculated anyway. I find the use of the intermediate value theorem useful in this situation, however Shashaank's answer seems more appropriate in the line of regular algebra. Thanks anyway