# Finding the range of $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$. How to take into account the discontinuity at $x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The task is: Determine the range of values ​​of the function

$$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$$

I did this:

$   y=f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}\\y=\frac{x^2+1}{x}\;/\cdot x\\x^2-xy+1=0\\D=b^2-4ac\ge0\\y^2-4\ge0\Longrightarrow y\le -2\; \vee \; y\ge 2
   $

Question :

> It is not clear to me how nowhere did we take into account that for $x = 0$ the function is not defined, ie. how are we sure that the codomain of a given function will be equal to those values ​​of $y$− a for which the solutions of the quadratic equation $x^2−xy+1 = 0 $ are real? Is there any reason why this is so?

No other approach to the task (other than this template) is known to me. I would really like to know another way (which is not based on a template) of approaching this type of task.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You inherently took into account that $x\neq 0$. If $x=0$, then $f(x)$ is not defined. Further, you took LCM by $x$ which would not be defined. Moreover, when you multiplied it to $y$, it would say that you have multiplied the co-domain by $0$. In the next step, $x^2-xy+1$, if you put $x=0$, then we have $1=0$(which I suppose is not supported by well-ordering principle.

Comment: forget about $x=0$ consider the function over the domain $(-\infty, -1] \cup [1,\infty)$ you will see that even with this restricted domain the function maps to $(-\infty, -2]\cup [2,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

We have that for $x>0$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+ }f(x)=\infty\quad\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=\infty$$

moreover by rearrangement inequality (or by AM-GM) we can see that

$$f(x)=x+\frac1x=1\cdot x+1\cdot \frac1x \ge x\cdot \frac1x+1\cdot 1=2$$

with equality for $x=1$.

Therefore for $x>0$, $f(x)$ has a positive minimum equal to $2$ and its range is $[2,\infty)$.

Finally, since the function is odd and not defined at $x=0$, we can conclude that its range is

$$(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$$

Comment: Can you explain this inequality? $1\cdot x+1\cdot \frac1x \ge x\cdot \frac1x+1\cdot 1
 $

Comment: @SrdjanPesevic I've used [Rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

Comment: Ok, but I don't quite understand...
Can you clarify that a little bit?
Thank you in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can be justified:

- You have already shown that if $f(x) = y$ then necessarily $x^2-xy+1 = 0$ and therefore $y^2 \ge 4$.
- On the other hand, if $y^2 \ge 4$ then $x^2-xy+1 = 0$ has a solution $x$, **and that solution cannot be zero.** Therefore $f(x) = y$ for some $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Putting it together, the range of $f$ is the set of all $y$ with $y^2 \ge 4$, that is $(-\infty, -2] \cup [2, \infty)$.

Comment: Not new: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1910014/505767

Comment: Moreover the asker is looking for a different way: "I would really like to know another way (which is not based on a template) of approaching this type of task".

Comment: @user: I have tried to answer the explicit question *“It is not clear to me how nowhere did we take into account that for $x = 0$ the function is not defined, ie. how are we sure that the codomain of a given function will be equal to those values ​​of $y$  for which the solutions of the quadratic equation $x^2−xy+1 = 0 $ are real? Is there any reason why this is so? ”*

Comment: @user: OP asks *why* an approach as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1910032/42969 gives the correct solution.

Comment: @user: I cannot see any close vote on the question so far, so apparently you don't consider it a duplicate either.

Comment: I think all given answers here are fine and can be useful to the asker and future users.

Answer (score 1):

The function rule is not well defined when $x=0$.

Hence we let our domain be $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. We can define our codomain to be $\mathbb{R}$, we just need our codomain to be a superset of the range.

Let $y$ be an element of the range, hence we must be able to find some real $x$ such that.

$$y=x+\frac1x$$

$$x^2-xy+1=0$$

For $x$ to be real, the discriminant is nonnegative, That is why we get the condition that we must have $y^2-4 \ge 0$ which is equivalent to $|y| \ge 2$.

For alternative, you can use AM-GM or calculus.

Notice that $f$ is an odd function, hence we can first study the restriction on the set of positive number.

Also, we have $f(x)=f(\frac1x)$, it suffices to study the behavior on $[1, \infty)$.

$$f'(x) = 1-\frac1{x^2} \ge 0 \text{ if } x \ge 1.$$

and $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$$

We know that $f(1)=2$, hence the range is $(-\infty, -2] \cup [2, \infty)$.